# picking out worksheet with maximum date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select a sheet from the workbook that has the newest date. The date is in the same space for each sheet, otherwise it is blank or text, and therefore should never evaluate as greater than an integer or date formatted value i think. Once i have found that sheet i want to take specific data and use it. My problem is selecting the correct sheet. Here is the code:

```
Dim wksht As Worksheet
Dim maxsheet As Worksheet
Dim currentdate as Integer
Dim maxdate as Integer

'go through each worksheet. compare the value of current date extracted from each sheet
'to maxdate. If currentdate > maxdate maxdate = currentdate.
'remember the worksheet for maxdate as maxsheet.

maxdate = 0
For Each wksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With wksht
        currentdate = wksht.Range("B1").Value
        If currentdate > maxdate Then
            maxsheet = wksht
            maxdate = currentdate
        End If
    End With
Next wksht
```

What is going on? The error i get is "'91': Object variable or with block variable not set." I don't really understand the help section or how i can fix it.

Looking at the code again i foresee another problem, working with the sheet once i have the sheet stored. Can i just use maxsheet.select for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop logic looks good to me. You're correct that the `With wksht`/`End With` are not being used. To use, it would be:

```
For Each wksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With wksht
        currentdate = .Range("B1").Value ` <~~~~ This guy right here
        If currentdate > maxdate Then
            maxsheet = wksht
            maxdate = currentdate
        End If
    End With
Next wksht
```

Now, without knowing a bit more about your worksheets I'm not sure I can answer your problem specifically, however, I would redo the logic to something like this:

### [Untested]

```
Dim currentdate as Date
Dim maxdate as Date
For Each wksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    if IsDate(wksht.Range("B1").Value) then    
        currentdate = CDate(wksht.Range("B1").Value)
        If currentdate > maxdate Then
            set maxsheet = wksht
            maxdate = currentdate
        End If
    end if
Next wksht
```

http://p2p.wrox.com/access-vba/11341-convert-text-date-time-access.html

Comment: let me see if i understand this: for each worksheet in the active workbook, it will check to see if the value of B1 of that sheet is a date. if not it will convert it to a date and assign it to current date. then it compares the currentdate to max date, etc. What about checking to see if the value of B1 for each sheet is a date and then if it is compare. Would that work as well? Also, what is the "continue" in the if not line? Do i need to initialize max date to some date for comparison? Thank you

Comment: You're right to question my `continue`... I forgot that it isn't a keyword in VBA and I have edited my answer so it won't confuse others.  Sorry about that =/ The edited code uses `IsDate(...)` to check if the value in B1 is a date. If it is, then it will do all of the date comparisons and other date-related stuff. If it isn't then the entire body of the loop is skipped and the loop moves on to the next worksheet. This will prevent problems in the off chance that someone typed some text into B1 on one of the worksheets.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You're initializing `currentdate` and `maxdate` as an `integer`; use the `date` datatype.
2. You have `maxsheet = wksht`, when it should be `set maxsheet = wksht`.

As for your other problem, yes, you can use `maxsheet.select`, specify a range (`maxsheet.range("B4")` for example), depending on what data you need to retreive.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your `currentdate` and `maxdate` variables to `date` type and change `maxsheet` to `string` type, then change the line to read `maxsheet = wksht.name` you'll capture the name of the page.  Then you can then refer to that page with `Worksheets(maxsheet)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim maxdate as Date
Dim wksht as Worksheet
Dim currentdate as Date
dim maxsheet as string

maxdate = 0
For Each wksht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If IsDate(wksht.Range("B1").Value) Then
        currentdate = CDate(wksht.Range("B1").Value)
        If currentdate > maxdate Then
            maxsheet = wksht.Name

            maxdate = currentdate
        End If
    End If
Next wksht
```

Thanks to all your help. This is the working code